# What is the Visual Studio 08 C# Assembly Information GUID setting for?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, publishing

I am developing a C# Application and I was verifying the setting for publishing the application.  What is the GUID setting under the Assembly Information section?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's used if you intend calling your .NET assembly from COM.

This [article](http://www.orcca.on.ca/~elena/useful/CallingDotNetCodeFromCom.html) describes the steps.